# maximum chain and maximum anti chain problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Can anyone help me on this?

Consider the divisibility partial order on $A$, so $a ≤ b$ if $b = ma$ for some integer $m$. Is this a total order? I need to write a maximum chain and maximum anti chain if they exist.

set $A=\{0,1,3,8,9\}$

I Know that to be a a total order , it need to obey:

If $a ≤ b$ and $b ≤  a$ then $a = b$ -antisymmetry

If $a ≤ b$ and $b ≤  c$ then $a ≤ c$ -transitivity

If For all $a$ and $b$, either $a ≤ b$ or $b ≤  a$ -totality

Also I can understand the divisibility partial order when analysing a practical example, but in this case I do not know how to start.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What is the set $A$?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention set A={0,1,3,8,9}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divisibility is not a total order on that set. You already know that it's a partial order on any positive set of integers, so it's anti-symmetric and transititve. What you need to care about is the totality.

But take $a=3$ and $b=8$. Then neither $a$ divides $b$, nor $b$ divides $a$.

Comment: So should I say that it is not a total order since not the tree conditions are met?  I do not understand the divisibility partial order in this problem can you explain?

Comment: for example I did: 1<=3<=9<=0 and 8<=0

Comment: Yes, it's not a total order, since not all of the three conditions are true. Are you asking why it is a partial order? In fact, I believe that partial orders are usual assumed to be reflexive ($a\leq a$ for all $a$), which the divisibility order on $A$ isn't, because $0$ is in $A$.

Comment: @user290335 yeah, that is true. Also, $1\leq 8$.

Comment: OK, got it. What about the maximum chain and maximum antichain? Is there any for this case?

Comment: @user290335 Yeah, $1\leq 3\leq 9\leq 0$ is a nice chain. As for an anti-chain, you can take $\{3,8\}$.

Comment: So 1≤3≤9≤0 would be an example of a maximum chain and {3,8} the maximum antichain ?

Comment: @user290335 yeah, you got it. :)